# Merging list of maps in gremlin

Tags: gremlin

I have this relationship:

`person --likes--> subject`

This is my query:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('person').
  has('name', 'Joe').
  outE('likes').
  range(0, 2).
  union(identity(), inV().hasLabel('subject')).
  valueMap('rating', 'name').
```

At this point, I get result that looks like this:

```
 [
      {
        "rating": 3.236155563
      },
      {
        "rating": 3.162886797
      },
      {
        "name": "math"
      },
      {
        "name": "history"
      }
]
```

I'd like to get something like this:

```
 [
      {
        "rating": 3.236155563,
        "name": "math"
      },
      {
        "rating": 3.162886797,
        "name": "history"
      },
]
```

I've tried grouping the results - which gives me the structure I want -  but because of the identical keys, I only get 1 set of results back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps when you post the code to create the graph so we can give you a tested answer. Like so

```
g.addV('person').property('name', 'P1').as('p1').
  addV('subject').property('name', 'Math').as('math').
  addV('subject').property('name', 'History').as('history').
  addV('subject').property('name', 'Geography').as('geography').
  addE('likes').from('p1').to('math').property('rating', 1.2).
  addE('likes').from('p1').to('history').property('rating', 2.3).
  addE('likes').from('p1').to('geography').property('rating', 3.4)
```

I believe you are trying to write a traversal that starts from a certain person, go out along the first two "likes" edges and get the names of the subjects that he likes and the rating on the corresponding "likes" edge.

```
g.V().has('person', 'name', 'P1').
  outE('likes').
  range(0, 2).
  project('SubjectName', 'Rating').
    by(inV().values('name')).
    by(values('rating'))
```

Comment: Verified it's working, thanks so much!  Unfortunately I'm just a downstream consumer of the graph and couldn't provide that detail.